# Duplicating an instance into a new VPC from a Snapshot

Tags: amazon-ec2

We have a group of instances in an Amazon VPC we use for our live environment.

We have a big release to do and want to test that the deployment will run smoothly.

I have created a second VPC, created instances of the same size on the same private ips and then removed their original volumes and attached new volumes that were created from snapshots of the live environment.

Unfortunately none of the instance will allow me to connect. They start running fine, but I don't get any system logs appear and can't connect.

The only thing I can think of is that the new instance was created from a new AMI as the old one is deprecated due to new security fixes.

Is this a problem? If so can I fix it in any way? And if this isn't a problem, does anyone have any ideas how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be better off creating your own AMIs from those snapshots and launching the new instances from those AMIs.

I've had the same problem when trying to swap root volumes in the past.

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying when you sent this reply and it worked! Thanks :)

I then retested the old snapshots and they now work on the instances based on the AMIs, so for all future tests I can snapshot and attach new volumes, without having to AMI them again, which seems to put the server into a busy state while it is done!